# Changing a matrix by multiplying indexes of min element

Tags: c

I need to make the following C program: Given A (N, N) matrix (2D array). The program needs to find the min element in each column. Then it needs to multiply the row in which the element is, with the difference of its indexes (a[i] * i - j). Then transfer the new row on another matrix. Print the new matrix.

Here is my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>

void InputArray(int a[][50],int M, int *N);
void NewArray(int a[][50], int b [][50], int N);
void PrintA(int a[][50], int N);
void PrintB(int b[][50], int N);

void main(){
    int a[50][50], b[50][50], N;
    InputArray(a, 50, &N);
    system("cls");
    NewArray(a, b, N);
    PrintA(a, N);
    PrintB(b, N);
}
void InputArray(int a[][50], int M, int *N){
    do{
        printf("Enter rows and columns: ");
        scanf("%d", N);
    } while (*N < 1 || *N > M);

    for (int i = 0; i < *N; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < *N; j++){
            printf("Enter i[%d][%d] element ", i, j);
            scanf("%d", &a[i][j]);
        }
    }
}

void NewArray(int a[][50], int b[][50], int N){
    int i, j, min, d, k, rowb = 0, rowa = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++){
        min = a[0][i];   
        d = 0 - i;      
        for (j = 0; j < N; j++){ 
            if (a[j][i] < min){
                min = a[j][i];
                d = j - i;
                rowa = j;
            }
        }

        for (k = 0; k < N; k++){
            b[rowb][k] = a[rowa][k] * d;
        }
        rowb++;
    }
}
void PrintA(int a[][50], int N){
    printf("You've entered: \n");
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++){  
        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++){
            printf("%d  ", a[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n");
}
void PrintB(int b[][50], int N){
    printf("New matrix is :\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++){
            printf("%d  ", b[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

It does work, but I think it the "NewArray" function can be made better.

Here is an example output:

```
You've entered:
1 4 9
2 6 5
3 8 2
New matrix is:
0 0 0 
-1 -4 -9
0 0 0
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by making `NewArray` "better"?

Comment: I feel like its not quite readable and I've used more variables than needed.

Comment: "needs to multiply the row in which the element is, with its indexes." lacks clarity. Sounds like each element of the row should be multiplied by `i*j`.  Please verify/explain further.

Comment: I tried to explain better, hope its clear now.

Comment: it's better to ask this question on SO as this site for reviewing already working programs. but in a nutshell, my suggestion is to logically divide you NewArray method. at first step populate min_values[50] array, at second calculate values for b[][50]. this way it's easier to get what is going on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use error detection**

With non-numeric input, `scanf("%d", N);` and following code will not function as expected.  Handle bad input.  For now, simple whine and take your toys home.  Later you can add more sophisticated error handling.

```
void InputArray(int a[][50], int M, int *N){
    // scanf("%d", N);
    if (scanf("%d", N) != 1) {
      perror("Invalid size");
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
```

**Seek clarification or state functionality on edge cases**

"program needs to find the min element in each column. Then it needs to multiply the row in which the element is, with the difference of its indexes".  What should happen if the min value occurs twice?

**Fold like functions together**

Only difference between `PrintA()` and `PrintB()` is the header text.  Pass that in.

```
void PrintArray(const char *header, const int a[][50], int N){
    fputs(header, stdout);
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++){  
        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++){
            printf("%d  ", a[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n");
}
...
PrintArray("You've entered:\n", a, N);
PrintArray("New matrix is :\n", b, N);
```

**Avoid naked magic numbers**

Rather than code `50` in many places, define it once and use that.

```
#defined ARRAY_DIM_MAX 50
// int a[50][50], b[50][50], N;
// InputArray(a, 50, &N);
int a[ARRAY_DIM_MAX][ARRAY_DIM_MAX], b[ARRAY_DIM_MAX][ARRAY_DIM_MAX], N;
InputArray(a, ARRAY_DIM_MAX, &N);
```

Further, consider using different constant names should you later want a rectangle matrix.  Even if both are 50, this better self documents the code.  Recommend to *not* declare many variables declares on a line.

```
#defined ARRAY_ROW_SZ 50
#defined ARRAY_COL_SZ 50

// int a[50][50], b[50][50], N;
// InputArray(a, 50, &N);
int a[ARRAY_ROW_SZ][ARRAY_COL_SZ];
int b[ARRAY_ROW_SZ][ARRAY_COL_SZ];
int N = 0; // Defensive coding to assign simple small objects.
InputArray(a, ARRAY_ROW_SZ, &N);
```

---

Minor stuff

**No need for `j==0` iteration**

```
for (i = 0; i < N; i++){
    min = a[0][i];   
    d = 0 - i;      
    // for (j = 0; j < N; j++){ 
    for (j = 1; j < N; j++){
```

**Use `const` when referenced data is unchanged**

This allows for wider applications, convey to users of the function of data involatility and may allow additional optimizations.

```
// void PrintA(int a[][50], int N){
void PrintA(const int a[][50], int N){
```

**Use standard signatures**

`void main()` may be acceptable on your platform, but not others.   Better to return `int`.

**Avoid non-portable code**

`system("cls");` is non-standard.

**Use `size_t`**

For array sizing and indexing, `size_t` is the Goldilocks type, neither not too narrow nor too wide.  As you develop, use that rather than `int` for indexing.  `int` is OK for learner code.

```
// void InputArray(int a[][50], int M, int *N){
void InputArray(int a[][50], size_t M, size_t *N){
```